# can't changing learning_rate in tensorflow optimizer during training

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

can someone explain me why I cant change the `learningrate` during training, in the old Optimizer I could change it with `self.updates.append(K.update(self.learning_rate, new_learning_rate))` but cant do it anymore and the `self._set_hyper("learning_rate", new_learning_rate)` doesn't work, it tells me that: `TypeError:__array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

```
class SGD(keras.optimizers.Optimizer):
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.01, name="SGD", **kwargs):
        """Call super().__init__() and use _set_hyper() to store hyperparameters"""
        super().__init__(name, **kwargs)
        self._set_hyper("learning_rate", kwargs.get("lr", learning_rate)) # handle lr=learning_rate
        
    @tf.function
    def _resource_apply_dense(self, grad, var):
        learning_rate = self._get_hyper("learning_rate")
        new_learning_rate = learning_rate * 0.001
        new_var_m = var - grad * new_learning_rate
        self._set_hyper("learning_rate", new_learning_rate) #dont work
        var.assign(new_var)

    def _resource_apply_sparse(self, grad, var):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def get_config(self):
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return {
            **base_config,
            "learning_rate": self._serialize_hyperparameter("learning_rate"),
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you can access the attribute set with `_set_hyper` directly, as mentionned in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer?hl=en#hyperparameters_2) :

> Hyperparameters can be overwritten through user code

As it is a `tf.Variable`, you can then use `assign` to set a new value with your `tf.Tensor` :

```
class SGD(keras.optimizers.Optimizer):
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.01, name="SGD", **kwargs):
        """Call super().__init__() and use _set_hyper() to store hyperparameters"""
        super().__init__(name, **kwargs)
        self._set_hyper("learning_rate", kwargs.get("lr", learning_rate)) # handle lr=learning_rate
        
    @tf.function
    def _resource_apply_dense(self, grad, var):
        learning_rate = self._get_hyper("learning_rate")
        new_learning_rate = learning_rate * 0.001
        new_var_m = var - grad * new_learning_rate
        self.learning_rate.assign(new_learning_rate)
        var.assign(new_var_m)
```